Sigma sum notation. I just started out with some basic questions and soon stumbled on this.
$\sum_{k=1}^{7} \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{ k^2 }+\sqrt[3]{ k(k+1) }+\sqrt[3]{ (k+1)^2 }}$
Started on the question, but could not do much. I tried to rationalize but I failed. I am really thinking rationalizing is the key to solve the problem.
I tried to factorize it by adding and subtracting
$\sqrt[3]{k(k+1)}$
So, I got:
$\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{ k^2 }+2\sqrt[3]{ k(k+1) }+\sqrt[3]{ (k+1)^2 }-\sqrt[3]{ k(k+1)}}$
I took $\sqrt[3]{k}$
common from first two terms in denominator.
and $\sqrt[3]{k+1}$ from last two terms.
I left me with
$\sum_{k=1}^{7} \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{k}(\sqrt[3]{k}+2\sqrt[3]{k+1})+\sqrt[3]{k+1}(\sqrt[3]{k+1}-\sqrt[3]{k})}$
Now I am feeling that I have overcomplicated my problem.
Rationalizing this seems way off than before.

Show your attempts. This isn’t a homework site.

Sorry, but I forgot. This isn't a homework problem. I am a grade 8 student. Sorry.

$$a^3 - b^3 = (a-b)(a^2 + ab + b^2)$$
$$ \sqrt[3]{ k^2 }+\sqrt[3]{ k(k+1) }+\sqrt[3]{ (k+1)^2} = \frac{(\sqrt[3]{ k+1 } - \sqrt[3]{ k} ) ( \sqrt[3]{ k^2 }+\sqrt[3]{ k(k+1) }+\sqrt[3]{ (k+1)^2} )}{\sqrt[3]{ k+1 } - \sqrt[3]{ k}} =  \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{ k+1 } - \sqrt[3]{ k}}$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{7} \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{ k^2 }+\sqrt[3]{ k(k+1) }+\sqrt[3]{ (k+1)^2 }} = \sum_{k=1}^{7}  (\sqrt[3]{ k+1 } - \sqrt[3]{ k}) = \sum_{k=1}^{7} (a_{k+1}-a_k) = a_8-a_1,$$
where $$a_k = \sqrt[3]{ k }.$$

So, for factorizing we have to multiply whatever we can in order to get an identity?

@MathBOT00101 Sometimes yes, as in this problem
